# Is there a way to log all incoming kafka requests in spring?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using simple kafka handler:

```
@KafkaListener(
  topics = Topic.NAME,
  clientIdPrefix = KafkaHandler.LISTENER_ID)
public class KafkaHandler {
  public static final String LISTENER_ID = "kafka_listener";

  @KafkaHandler(isDefault = true)
  @Description(value = "Event received")
  public void onEvent(@Payload Payload payload) {
    ...
  }
```

However, my object (Payload in the example) is not mapped properly (some fields are null).
Is there a way to log all incoming kafka KV pairs somewhere in spring-kafka app?

Answer (score 0):

You can process the entire Kafka record instead only the payload.

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "any-topic")
void listener(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {
    log.info("{}",record.key());
    log.info("{}",record.value());
    log.info("{}",record.partition());
    log.info("{}",record.topic());
    log.info("{}",record.offset());
}
```

Replace the String for your desired key, value format, and  define the deserializer class in your app properties.

```
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=YourKeyDeserializer.class
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=YourValueDeserializer.class
```